Network activity halting at every 45s
I have a lot of Linux boxes, mostly debian 10-11-12, where, on some of them (I'd say about 20% of them) the networking activity stops at fixed intervals (usually 45s). By "stops" I mean rx/tx is exactly as the previous second:
cat /sys/class/net/eno1/statistics/rx_bytes
cat /sys/class/net/eno1/statistics/tx_bytes

I only noticed this after implementing a monitor due to some complaints I had. Now, I can't find the culprit. I tried making a delta of processes suspecting something like a cron but I have nothing. Cron is disabled, I don't see anything suspect.
Where do you suggest I should be looking so I can detect whatever is causing this?
Updates for more info:
lspci | grep -E -i --color 'network|ethernet'
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe

root@debian:~# ip monitor dev eno1
xxx.xx.x.1 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.1 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.1 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.0 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.1 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.0 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.1 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.0 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.1 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.0 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.0 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.0 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.1 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.0 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.0 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.0 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.1 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.0 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.0 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.1 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.1 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.0 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.1 FAILED
xxx.xx.x.1 FAILED

journalctl --system -b -x does not show anything during these events
ip link show

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 51:9f:35:18:22:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0f0
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 51:9f:35:18:22:91 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0f1
4: eno3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 51:9f:35:18:22:92 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0f0
5: eno4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 51:9f:35:18:22:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0f1
9: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 500
    link/none

and
ethtool eno1

Settings for eno1:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                         1000baseT/Full
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    MDI-X: off
    Supports Wake-on: g
    Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x000000ff (255)
                               drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err
    Link detected: yes


To what kind of network are they connected? I guess eno1 implies classic Gigabit Ethernet? Do they happen to use the same network interface card type (in that case, which one?)? Since rx_bytes doesn't increase, the card must either really physically receive no packets (for example, if the switch they're attached to stops switching packets towards them), or explicitly shut down by software; the latter, you'd be very likely to see in journalctl --system -b -x. Or, even better, in ip monitor dev eno1?

I updated the original question. Those FAILED prints take place much faster than the actual drops and the intervals are nor similar either. Thank you.

if neither ip monitor sees any device stat changes, then, from the linux kernel's point of view, the device remains there. Assuming the driver would log errors (which you'd see in journalctl) if the card itself stops responding and needs to be re-initialized… hm. Either this is a hardware fault with the card, or something goes wrong with the (probably relatively complex, considering your cards) switch they're connected to. One idea: can you go and actually check whether the port LED (either on the NIC end or the switch end) keeps blinking during these outage periods? If so –> hard/firmware

Unfortunately I do not have access to these boxes. They are rented. I will try to coordinate with someone and see if the LEDs stop blinking but it's a bit hard in this period.

hm, maybe your switch has link state monitoring itself? could be another interesting data point. The other thing that just came to my mind: maybe play around with "tunables" in ethtool, especially power down and mode switch intervals. Maybe read every one that specifies a time, and see if any of these times happen to be 45 s.

Checking logs on the switch (if any) would be interesting.  Less likely, check arp cache.

Fire on one of your problematic machine
tcpdump -n -i eno1 broadcast or stp

and look for any STP broadcast storm.
Next you will have to identify if this is due to a real physical loop
in your network or a total misbehaving of STP in the case you have too many
hosts implememting it.

There is no problematic STP storm. 15:35:03.079195 STP 802.1d, Config, Flags [none], bridge-id 8011.00:1c:58:d6:bc:c0.801e, length 35 prints at about 3-4 seconds each but nothing crazy during a halt, before or after

It sounds like you have your NICs speed set to "auto", and, for some reason (down in the weeds), every 45 seconds, the NICs renegotiate the link speed.
No packets move across the link while this happens.
Check your link speed with
ip link show

and, after picking a speed, use
ip link set dev XXX speed YYY

('XXX' is the device name, and 'YYY' is the speed you picked.
All of the renegotiating happens at Layer 1 of the OSI model. There's no logging at Layer 1. By selecting a speed, you disable auto-negotiation.
Of course, read man ip ip-link. If your systems don't have ip, you can probably address the problem with ifconfig, read man ifconfig.

If you can access the switch and confirm that it isn't a junkheap that has trouble recomputing the spanning-tree every-45seconds (hmm, not 30s or 60s, 45s -- aren't ARP...)

Thank you for the suggestions. I've edited the question so it now reflects your debugging also. I did not see anything suspect. I think it show it is running at optimal speeds.

Your ethtool output shows several "auto negotiation: yes". That's your problem. Pick a speed, for either or both, then restart networking.

It's off now but I get the same results unfortunately. Networking seems to have restarted itself when I applied with: ethtool -s eno1 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg off

I really would not recommend disabling autonegotiation. Especially not for Gigabit Ethernet, where it is mandatory – but also in principle, because NICs re-negotiating the speed is not something that would normally happen on a regular basis unless the physical connection itself is bad; doing this is very much "painting over" the problem and not actually solving it. (And if you do disable autonegotiation, then you must configure the same speed on both ends of the link, otherwise the link likely won't come up at all as the other end will likely fall back to 10Mbps mode.)

Never set fixed link speed. If cards re-negotiate it's because they have lost link. In that case, fix whatever problem causes them to drop the link. I would agree with athena's answer as a likely culprit, and would check switch logs for STP related issues.

Review your switch's logs for the ports you're connected to; perhaps they'll provide some detail. Also, if possible, review the switch in relation to errors accumulating on the affected ports. In cases where consistent connectivity is important, a managed switch that records such information is very helpful.
